# Javascript onmouseout Sleep?

Tags: javascript, onmouseout

In Javascript, I want my onmouseout event to sleep/pause/wait/ (not sure of the proper terminology here) for three seconds before taking effect. How is that accomplished?

thanks

Comment: The term I would use is defer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function outfunction(event) {
    var that = this; // to be able to use this later.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        …
    /* you can use 'that' here to refer to the element
       event is also available in this scope */
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: You ought to pass the event object to out, and to the inner anonymous function.

Comment: one cannot pass it to the inner function but it works because the anonymous function uses the scope of the outer function.

Comment: Accessing the event object in the inner function is dubious, better would be to acquire any info needed from the event object into variables in the outer function.

Comment: But so is using 'that', and I know of no way to circumvent that, besides using another anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var doSomething = function () {
    //Some code will here after 3 seconds of mouseout
};

anElement.onmouseout = function () {
   setTimeout(doSomething, 3000);
};
```

What the above code does is execute the `doSomething` function after 3 seconds of the `onmouseout` being invoked